# On click event not working with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jQuery to attach an on click handler for one of my drop down modals. I use the same syntax to open the modal, and it works fine. But when I want to close the modal the on click does not seem to work.

```js
// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
$("#requestQuoteNavMap").click(function() {
  $("#myModal").show();
});

// When the user clicks close, close the modal
$("#close").click(function() {
  $("#myModal").hide();
});
```

```css
.modal {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.close {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  font: bold 20px Verdana;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="requestQuoteNavMap">
  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" id="modal-header">
        <span class="close" id="close">×</span>
        <h3 class="modalHeaderTxt">Header</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!--content here-->
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer" id="modal-footer">Post</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The best way to close a modal is only with data-dismiss="modal" on the span.close

Comment: What is the relation between '_anywhere outside of the modal_' and `#close`?

Comment: @palaѕн old comment, fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the close button is within the div `requestQuoteNavMap`, any click on the close button will also be recognized as a click on the div. This will trigger both click events thereby first hiding and then showing the modal.

To prevent this you need to stop the click event from *bubbling* or *propagating* up to the close button's parent (the div) when it is clicked. You can do this by calling [`event.stopPropagation`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) from within the click event of the close button.

e.g.

```
$("#close").click(function(event) {
  $("#myModal").hide();
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: worked like a charm, what exactly do you mean by bubbling up to the close button's parent? Why is it doing that?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a jsfiddle showing what's up.

https://jsfiddle.net/e4tw7d5k/13/

When you click close, you're firing both click events right now, because close is inside the #requestQuoteNavMap.  Events in javascript fire on the element you click first, and then "bubble up" to every element one at a time that contains that element.  Usinging `event.stopPropagation()` will prevent the click event from propogating (bubbling up) to any other elements.

```js
// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
$("#requestQuoteNavMap").click(function(){ 
  $("#myModal").show();
});

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
$("#close").click(function(e){ 
 e.stopPropagation();
  $("#myModal").hide(); 
});
```

```css
.modal {
  display: block;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="requestQuoteNavMap">
    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" id="modal-header">
                <a href="#" class="close" id="close">×</a>
                <h3 class="modalHeaderTxt">Header</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!--content here-->
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" id="modal-footer">Post</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```